# r: when to use if else loops vs. functions

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, dplyr

Need your help to resolve a loop issue;

Example data:

```
data2 <- structure(list(a = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108,109,110), 
                         b = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4),
                         c = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3,3,3)), 
          .Names = c("ID", "Band", "Group_qty"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Example desired output:

```
Output <- structure(list(a = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110), 
                          b = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4),
                          c = c(4,4,4,4,2,2,1,3,3,3),
                          d = c(102,103,104,103,"Class B","Class B","Class A",109,110,109)), 
                     .Names = c("ID", "Band", "Group_qty","NewID"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Draft if else statement:
Note: This doesn't work.

```
data2$NewID <- 
  for(i in 1:length(data2$ID))
  {
    ifelse(data2$[i,3] == 1, "Class A", ifelse(data2[i,3] == 2, "Class B", ifelse(data2[i,2] == data2[i+1,2], data2[i+1,1], data2[i-1,1])))
  }
```

Question:

How do I create a working loop or function that I can use with dplyr.
Rules:

1. If Group_qty = 1; Output = Class A
2. If Group_qty = 2; Output = Class B
3. Else, check to see if the Band match the Band of the next row.

   - IF YES, Output = The next row's ID
   - IF NO, Output = Previous row's ID
4. Once we reach the last row of the loop - we will not have a row+1. In that case: Output = Previous row's ID.
5. Can this be resolved using dplyr & mutate. If yes, would love to have that as a possible answer.

Thanks,

Comment: I changed literally two things about your loop 1) `sapply` to return the results and 2) `%in%` instead of `==` to deal with NAs better, there is absolutely no reason to introduce a package for this one task `sapply(1:length(data2$ID), function(i) ifelse(data2[i,3] %in% 1, "Class A", ifelse(data2[i,3] %in% 2, "Class B", ifelse(data2[i,2] %in% data2[i+1,2], data2[i+1,1], data2[i-1,1]))))`

Comment: @rawr - You could do it without a loop or packages too, albeit not very prettily: `data2$NewID <- NA;tband <- c(tail(data2$Band,-1),NA);lband <- data2$Band == tband;data2$NewID[which(lband)] <- c(tail(data2$ID,-1),NA)[which(lband)];data2$NewID[which(!lband)] <- c(NA,head(data2$ID,-1))[which(!lband)];data2$NewID[length(data2$NewID)] <- tail(data2$ID,2)[1];data2$NewID[data2$Group_qty == 1] <- "Class A";data2$NewID[data2$Group_qty == 2] <- "Class B"`

Comment: @thelatemail it's the purity that makes it beautiful

Comment: @rawr - Thank you guys. I did play with sapply & rapply, but couldn't get it to work. Thanks for showing me how. :)

Comment: @rawr. I am struggling with a json question that I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35346271/5855331. Would really appreciate your help on it if you have time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @J1975 sorry, don't know I've never done that stuff. sounds like from [here](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/CallRef/types/PaginationInput.html) you can send one request for up to 100 entries each. but also tack on `&paginationInput.pageNumber=n` to the end of your url and get specific page numbers, n. then you could loop over page numbers until there are no more results, combine the lists into one result and then do the aggregation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data2)`), grouped by 'Band', `if` the number of elements in the group is greater than 1 (`.N >1`), we use `shift` with `type='lead'` to get the succeeding 'ID' for each group or `else` keep the 'ID' to create the 'NewID' column.  Then, based on the condition, we replace the value in 'NewID' that corresponds to 'Group_qty' 2 as 'Class B' and 1 as 'Class_A' using `ifelse`.

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(data2)[, NewID:=if(.N>1) shift(ID, type='lead', 
                       fill = ID[.N-1]) else ID , by = .(Band)]
 data2[, NewID:= ifelse(Group_qty==2, 'Class B', 
                 ifelse(Group_qty==1, 'Class A', NewID))]
data2
#     ID Band Group_qty   NewID
# 1: 101    1         4     102
# 2: 102    1         4     103
# 3: 103    1         4     104
# 4: 104    1         4     103
# 5: 105    2         2 Class B
# 6: 106    2         2 Class B
# 7: 107    3         1 Class A
# 8: 108    4         3     109
# 9: 109    4         3     110
#10: 110    4         3     109
```

---

We can use a similar approach with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data2 %>%
    group_by(Band) %>% 
    mutate(NewID = if(n()==1) ID else dplyr::lead(ID, 
                         default= ID[n()-1]), 
           NewID= ifelse(Group_qty==2, 'Class B', 
                  ifelse(Group_qty==1, 'Class A', 
                        as.character(NewID))))
#     ID  Band Group_qty   NewID
#   (dbl) (dbl)     (dbl)   (chr)
#1    101     1         4     102
#2    102     1         4     103
#3    103     1         4     104
#4    104     1         4     103
#5    105     2         2 Class B
#6    106     2         2 Class B
#7    107     3         1 Class A
#8    108     4         3     109
#9    109     4         3     110
#10   110     4         3     109
```

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun. Can you please explain the "shift" & type='lead' & fill.

Comment: Complicated but "Brilliant". So with the Group by clause the Group_qty column is basically redundant. Question: Which part is the group by - is it the .(Band)?

Comment: Would love to compare it with a dplyr solution too. Not in terms of system time, but in terms of the actual code to help with my learning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jun1975 It is `by = .(Band)`.

Comment: @Jun1975 Updated with a dplyr option.

Comment: I am struggling with a json question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/35346271/5855331. Would really appreciate your help on it if you have time.